# Calling local function inside another local function

Tags: lua

The following snippet

```
local function foo ()
    print('inside foo')
    bar()
end

local function bar ()
    print('inside bar')
end

foo()
```

Results in the following output

```
inside foo
lua: teste.lua:3: attempt to call global 'bar' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        teste.lua:3: in function 'foo'
        teste.lua:10: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

If I remove the modifier `local` from `bar` declaration then it works as expected, outputting

```
inside foo
inside bar
```

How can I call `bar` inside `foo` keeping both as `local`?

Comment: Lexical scope in Lua doesn't have backward-propagation. `bar` should be defines BEFORE it is used.  Place `bar` before `foo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define `bar` before `foo`.

```
local function bar ()
    print('inside bar')
end

local function foo ()
    print('inside foo')
    bar()
end

foo()
```

In your example, when you are inside the `foo` function, then as far as Lua is concerned `bar` doesn't exist yet. This means it defaults to a global variable with a value of `nil`, which is why you get the error "attempt to call global 'bar' (a nil value)".

If you want to define `foo` before `bar` and keep them both as local variables, you need to declare the bar variable first.

```
local bar

local function foo ()
    print('inside foo')
    bar()
end

function bar ()
    print('inside bar')
end

foo()
```

In this example, if you want to prove to yourself that `bar` is a local variable, you can add the following code at the end:

```
if _G.bar ~= nil then
    print("bar is a global variable")
else
    print("bar is a local variable")
end
```

This checks whether "bar" is a key in `_G`, the table of global variables.

Comment: I'm building a recursive descent parser where some rules call each other, so there is no way to define one before another. Declaring `local bar` at the top of the file really solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Last loop is invalid: if there is no global value, there also can be no local one. So correct way is to iterate via local and upvalue variables (like lua does). BTW, your loop is eqal to `if _G.bar ~= nil then`.

Comment: @val Yeah, not sure why I didn't code the _G part that way the first time - I edited my answer. To check for locals explicitly I guess you would have to use the debug library. That would take a bit more searching through documentation than I want to do right now, but if you want to edit the answer with the right code, go ahead. :)

Comment: @Gabriel is correct, local variables are declared, not defined. Functions have definitions (which creates a function value when evaluated). So, the second example is right on.

Answer (score 2):

In fact：

```
local function foo () end
```

Equivalent to

```
local foo  
foo = function() end
```

In Lua, a function is a first-class value. So, it is not usable before it is defined.